# Does hash aggregate not work with array_agg in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a query with a group by that either performs a sort followed by group aggregate or a hash aggregate. I noticed that when adding an array_agg function, the query never tries to perform a hash aggregate increasing the query time. I have set my work_mem for the transaction to a really high number so there is no memory constraint.

Does postgres never use hashaggregate if there is an array_agg function in the aggregation?

This is the format of the query in question:

```
SELECT
    "test"."db"."a",
    "test"."db"."b",
    "test"."db"."c",
    "test"."db"."d",
    "test"."db"."e",
    "test"."db"."f",
    "test"."db"."g",
    array_agg(ARRAY["test"."db"."resource_type", "test"."db"."resource_name", "test"."db"."pattern_type"]) FILTER (WHERE "test"."db"."deleted" is FALSE) AS "resources"
FROM
    "test"."db"
WHERE ("test"."db"."last_change_id" BETWEEN 0 AND val3
    AND "test"."db"."c" = 'val1'
    AND "test"."db"."d" = 'val2')
GROUP BY
    "test"."db"."a",
    "test"."db"."b",
    "test"."db"."c",
    "test"."db"."d",
    "test"."db"."e",
    "test"."db"."f",
    "test"."db"."g"
```

The plan executed is the following:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=180461.63..183740.70 rows=84788 width=147) (actual time=3310.049..3764.216 rows=119173 loops=1)
   Group Key: a, b, c, d, e, f, g
   ->  Sort  (cost=180461.63..180708.21 rows=98632 width=151) (actual time=3310.030..3394.925 rows=513793 loops=1)
         Sort Key: a, b, e, f, g
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 148765kB
         ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..172280.22 rows=98632 width=151) (actual time=2.590..478.026 rows=513793 loops=1)
               Workers Planned: 2
               Workers Launched: 2
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on role_binding  (cost=0.00..161417.02 rows=41097 width=151) (actual time=0.897..414.638 rows=171264 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((last_change_id >= 0) AND (last_change_id <= val3) AND (c = 'val1'::text) AND (d = 'val2'::text))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 826426
 Planning Time: 0.181 ms
 Execution Time: 3782.427 ms
```

Comment: Is there an `ORDER BY` clause in the aggregate function?

Comment: Perhaps you could add the queries and their respective plans to the question?

Comment: It can use a hash aggregate with array_agg.  Knowing why it doesn't in one particular case would depend on the details of the case, and maybe the version.

Comment: There is no order by in the aggregate function

Comment: I pasted the sample query and execution plan. I had to change some names around but basically the moment I remove the array_agg I see that it uses a hash aggregate in the query plan

Comment: @jjanes any ideas on why it wouldn't use hash aggregate?

Comment: In my hands I get partial hash aggregates (i.e. down inside the parallel workers).  But it still depends on the version.

Comment: @jjanes postgresql version 12.14

Answer (score 1):

In my hands in 12.9 it uses the hash agg as long as the work_mem is large enough that it is confident the data will fit in memory.  Without having your actual data, I don't know what large enough would mean for you, but a few Gig would probably do it.

In later versions, hash agg was taught to spill to disk, which makes the planner more eager to use it.

Comment: I set work_mem to 512MB, and the sort used 125MB.

Comment: I don't know if that means that it worked, or it didn't work.